# LongListSelector for Windows Store App

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs

Does anyone know if any of the WinRT Controls exposed via WinJS can be customized to offer the same look and feel as the [Windows Phone LongListSelector](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api)?

[image]

Comment: The WinJS controls are not WinRT controls. They're written in JavaScript, just like the rest of WinJS. Actually, there's no way to host a XAML control in IE or the metro HTML app container.

Comment: What about using CSS to customize your nested `<ol>` or `<ul>` list?

Comment: That is what I did in the end but without using a WinJS control in this particular case. Here's the result http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-US/app/zentomi-reader/01a9d53e-c533-4a9b-9fe0-543ddc54ac88

Answer (score 0):

The WinJS [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211837.aspx) is the right control for you. And for what I see, grouping is all you need.

Go to the [WinJS Playground](http://try.buildwinjs.com/playground/) and take a look at the `Grouped ListLayout`